# Making a stopwatch with an Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a stopwatch with an Arduino.
By multiplexing I can display a static number with a function I wrote:

```cpp
void display7s (int i, int j, int k, int l)
{
    while (1) {
        displayNumber(i, 4);
        delay(1);
        displayNumber(j, 3);
        delay(1);
        displayNumber(k, 2);
        delay(1);
        displayNumber(l, 1);
        delay(1);
    }
}
```

The `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` arguments are the numbers to display. `displayNumber` displays and convert numbers the second parameter of this function is the digit indeed the 7 segment display has 4 digits.

I don't know how to proceed to display an incrementing numbers from (0010 to 9999,...)
I'm stuck being able just to display static 4 digits numbers.

I know the way my function is written it can work because it's an infinite loop but but I'd like to combine this infinite loop and a 1000 ms delay to increase the time.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is decomposing a number into its individual digits, 
you can do it like this:

```cpp
while(1) {
    int n = 0;
    int i = n/1000; // x * 1000
    int j = n/100 % 10; // x * 100
    int k = n/10 % 10; // x * 10
    int l = n % 10; // x
    displayNumber(i,4);
    delay(1);
    displayNumber(j,3);
    delay(1);
    displayNumber(k,2);
    delay(1);
    displayNumber(l,1);
    delay(1000);
    n++;
    if(n>9999) n = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is actually your infinite loop adapted so it will show number n from n = 0 to n = 9999 and then repeat, with 1000ms in between succeeding numbers. Example:
0000, 
delay(1000),
0001, 
delay(1000), 
 ... 
9999,
delay(1000), 
0000, 
delay(1000), 
... again and again

Comment: If that is not what you wanted, please try to formulate the question differently. What should an example output look like?